# .Net Core 3 Asking for Namespace that already exists

Tags: .net-core, namespaces

Hoping someone can help, ive just updated some nuget packages (from .net core preview to 3) ran a build and now get an error saying:

```
The type name 'SqlConnection' could not be found in the namespace. This type has been forwarded to assembly Consider adding a reference to that assembly.
```

As you can see from the image below i have got the names in there. but i believe the grey means that it doesnt think its using it? and im getting the error.

Any ideas on how to fix the issue?

Thanks

[image]

Comment: Please check if the assembly reference is missing. Otherwise post your code

Comment: Hi, sorry, how do i do that?